# Should the directional parts of vectors be treated as a value or a line?

Tags: vectors

> Should the directional parts of vectors be treated as a value or a line?

Say $\newcommand{\veca}{\mathbf{a}}\newcommand{\vecb}{\mathbf{b}}\veca$ is some vector. We can write
$$\veca=|\veca|\hat{\veca}$$
where $|\veca|$ is the magnitude and $\hat{\veca}$ is the direction of the vector under consideration.

Now, my question is: is $\hat{\veca}$ a line? or a value? I mean, if we have two equal vectors $\veca$ and $\vecb$, then which one is correct?

Treating as a value,
$$\hat{\veca}=\hat{\vecb}$$
or treating as a line,
$$\hat{\veca}\,\|\,\hat{\vecb}$$

Comment: What is the difference, except for the symbols you used? In particular, where in *physics* do you think this matters?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: It can be used in some formal proofs. And I don't understand your first sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\hat a$ is just a vector of magnitude $\vert \hat a \vert =1$.  It would be correct to say $\hat a=\hat b$; it would also be correct to say $\hat a \parallel \hat b$, because we define the angle between $\hat a$ and $\hat b$ to be $\theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\hat a\cdot \hat b}{\vert \hat a \vert  \vert \hat b \vert}\right)$.  If $\hat a = \hat b$ then the angle between them is $\cos^{-1}(1) = 0$, and this is what we mean when we say that two vectors are parallel.

On the other hand, a *line* is not a vector, but rather a set of points in space.  If we choose a base point $\mathbf p = (x,y,z)$ then the set of points $\{\mathbf q \in \mathbb R^3 \ | \ \mathbf q = \mathbf p + \lambda \hat a \text{ for some }\lambda\in \mathbb R\}$ is a line, but that's different from $\hat a$ itself being a line.

Comment: Thanks, I got it! (I will accept it later as the interface says "You can accept in 2 minutes")